# Configure .httaccess to make wordpress accessed by multiple domain without redirect on nginx & apache server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

Hai I have a vestacp that running nginx and apache on CENTOS 7,
Short story I have install a wordpress with this address sub.domain.com,

Now I have setup ne domain.org that pointed to directory of wordpress instalation sub.domain.com.
and I have configure .httpd.conf and nginx.conf so the **domain.org** can show the project of **sub.domain.com**

I tried to access **domain.org/about** it works and display the information like **sub.domain.com**,

1. the problem is I need to type manualy */about* because in **domain.org** WP Post and Page url still showing **https://sub.domain.com/**
2. how to make **sub.domain.com** and **domain.org** still accessible with single WordPress installation,
   let say **sub.domain.com** is blocked in some country so they need new domain **domain.org** that accessible from blocked country,
   so **domain.org** will showing the same data as **sub.domain.com**, when **sub.domain.com** updated so **domain.org** is also updated

it's possible to replace the at wp_option table to **domain.org** but I want sub.domain.com still accessible

is there any other method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wordpress codex](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/) stated that you may directly override the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in your `wp-config.php` file:

```php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

Naturally, you may build your own domain from [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables.

```php
$scheme = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://';
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$home_path = '/somepath'; // only needed if your wordpress is in a subfolder.

define( 'WP_HOME', $scheme . $host . $home_path );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', $scheme . $host);
```

Then the links will be adaptive to the visiting domain.

You might think this is too hackish. Alternatively, you may install [Multiple Domain](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/). I haven't try it before, but it claims to achieve the same effect.

Please note that for [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) sake, this is not good. It is more optimal to have all traffics of the same post redirected to the same domain so it's Google's rating is better.